# Input type button/submit that does both form validation and submit via jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, input, validation

I am trying to use jquery validator plugin and form submit via ajax in jquery.....

Validator plugin works with `<input type="submit" value="Add a client" id="clientadd"/>` but my form submit works with `<input type="button" value="Add a client" id="clientadd"/>`.....

```
<form id="addform" autocomplete="off">
 //My controls here
</form>
```

I didn't specify `action` and `method` attributes here as i ll submit my form using `jquery.ajax()`.... Any suggestion how to get both working together....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify a [submitHandler](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) that will perform the form submission once validation succeeds:

```
$('form').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
       // TODO: submit your form in ajax here
    }
});
```

So if you are using the [jQuery.form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin to ajaxify your form:

```
$('form').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit();        
    }
});
```

Comment: @Pandiya, as always glad to help :-)

Comment: looked at your profile page and the MVC project structure  article was really nice... But NHibernate is really tough for me to get a hold on it...

Answer (score 1):

You can add `action=""` so it will be valid HTML, and use the `type="submit"` button without problems. Simply catch the submit with jQuery and prevent the normal submit from occuring:

```
$('#addform').submit(function() {
  // your stuff here to process the form

  // end with
  return false;
});
```